# IDA PRO Struct Pointer Counter big number not starting from address offset 0, Lowers a bit slightly but not completely to 0

Tags: struct, reverse-engineering, offset, memory-address, ida

I put the whole question in 3 images from research it seems I need to use `CTRL+R` but I don't think that's what I need since I could lower the number a bit lower just can't lower it to the proper amount of 0.

I think the problem is I'm not creating the structs properly probably missing something.

[image: problem 1]
[image: asm code]

ASM Code:

```
.text:0040E040 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:0040E040
.text:0040E040
.text:0040E040 ; struct_ARENA *__thiscall code(struct_PLAYER *player, const void *buf, unsigned int len, int a4)
.text:0040E040 sub_40E040      proc near               
.text:0040E040                                         
.text:0040E040
.text:0040E040 buf             = dword ptr  4
.text:0040E040 len             = dword ptr  8
.text:0040E040 a4              = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:0040E040
.text:0040E040                 push    ebx
.text:0040E041                 push    esi
.text:0040E042                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:0040E044                 mov     eax, [esi+1Ch]
.text:0040E047                 test    eax, eax
.text:0040E049                 jz      short loc_40E093
.text:0040E04B                 mov     ecx, [eax+0FF0Ch]
.text:0040E051                 xor     ebx, ebx
.text:0040E053                 test    ecx, ecx
.text:0040E055                 jle     short loc_40E093
.text:0040E057                 push    edi
.text:0040E058                 push    ebp
.text:0040E059                 mov     ebp, [esp+10h+a4]
.text:0040E05D                 mov     edi, 0FB20h
.text:0040E062
.text:0040E062 loc_40E062:                             
.text:0040E062                 mov     eax, [edi+eax]
.text:0040E065                 cmp     eax, esi
.text:0040E067                 jz      short loc_40E082
.text:0040E069                 mov     ecx, [eax+38h]
.text:0040E06C                 test    ecx, ecx
.text:0040E06E                 jnz     short loc_40E082
.text:0040E070                 mov     ecx, [esp+10h+len]
.text:0040E074                 mov     edx, [esp+10h+buf]
.text:0040E078                 push    ebp             ; a4
.text:0040E079                 push    ecx             ; len
.text:0040E07A                 push    edx             ; buf
.text:0040E07B                 mov     ecx, eax        ; this
.text:0040E07D                 call    SendPlayerReliablePacket
.text:0040E082
.text:0040E082 loc_40E082:                             
.text:0040E082                                         
.text:0040E082                 mov     eax, [esi+1Ch]
.text:0040E085                 inc     ebx
.text:0040E086                 add     edi, 4
.text:0040E089                 cmp     ebx, [eax+0FF0Ch]
.text:0040E08F                 jl      short loc_40E062
.text:0040E091                 pop     ebp
.text:0040E092                 pop     edi
.text:0040E093
.text:0040E093 loc_40E093:                            
.text:0040E093                                         
.text:0040E093                 pop     esi
.text:0040E094                 pop     ebx
.text:0040E095                 retn    0Ch
.text:0040E095 sub_40E040      endp
.text:0040E095 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0040E098                 align 10h
```

Here is one that looks better only 1 struct instead of 2 but still same problem

[image]